# Interactive rebase in main repo that affects submodule hashes

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-rebase

I have one main repo that contains multiple submodules that each have active development.

```
main_proj/
- sub1/
- sub2/
- sub3/
```

It is not uncommon for development in the main project to be performed in lock-step with one or more of the submodules.

```
1234abc main_proj commit 1
2345bcd main_proj commit 2
fedc987 submodule update1 for sub1                <-- only updates submodule hash
3456cde main_proj commit 3
edcb876 submodule update2 for sub1                <-- only updates submodule hash
aaaa001 submodule update1 for sub2                <-- updates main_proj AND submodule hash at same time
4567def main_proj commit 4
5678ef0 main_proj commit 5
cccc999 submodule update for sub1, sub2 and sub3  <-- updates submodule hashes
6789f01 main_proj commit 6
```

I want to run an interactive rebase on `main_proj` and rearrange the last two or three commits. Some of those commits, however, update the submodule hashes and therefore, causes merge conflicts:

> ```
> Auto-merging sub1
> CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in sub1
> error: could not apply 8792e483... Take 1
> Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
> You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
> To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
> Could not apply 8792e483... Take 1
> ```

Since the interactive rebase was intended to only work on files under `main_proj`, I will just re-apply the "submodule hash" commits once the work is done, so my ultimate commit will be pointing at all the currect submodule HEADs.

Is there a command during interactive rebase that I need to use in order to allow the commit to continue with "dirty" changes to the submodules?